# Create and Name Multiple files into R

Tags: r

I'm writing a script to create 100 files and name this files with numbers in sequence. ("1.txt", "2.txt", ..., "100.txt")

I tried to use a loop construction, but the file.create() function seems not to support vector args.

I can easily do it one by one, but i'm looking for an automatic solution in order to save time.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe use `?write.csv` or `?write.table` ? A reproducible example with your loop so far would be helpful as well.

Comment: please show the actual code you tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to loop, or use regex, or do any type conversion.

You can use a vector created with `sprintf()` (or `paste()`) in the `...` argument to `file.create()`

```
file.create(sprintf("%d.txt", 1:100))
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not familiarized with C language, but this helped me a lot.

Comment: I know it, but 'sprintf()' is a C function, isn't ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need.

```
s=as.character(seq(from = 1,to=100))
s=sub(x=s, pattern = "(.*)",replacement = "\\1.txt")
file.create(s)
```

Personally I would use some other language for that like perl/python or just bash.